# How to fix SVG map extension overlapping maps instead of displaying them separately

Tags: javascript, qliksense

I am using this extension for Qlik sense:
https://github.com/brianwmunz/svgReader-QlikSense

And I am trying to use it to get two maps side to side in my Qlik sense sheet. The problem is that when I try to do this, that I only get 1 object with two maps overlapping. Like this:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29434827/27138268-6c64add6-5120-11e7-9637-8cd166c4d988.png

I tried looking online for a solution but couldn't really find anything. I also tried looking into the .js files, but I can't figure it out. I figure that the problem is that the objects both load the map one at the time, but when the second object does it, it forces the other map to his location and making both maps overlap eachother. Problem is, I don't understand enough javascript to pinpoint the exact spot I need to comment out or change.

Hopefully you can help me with this. I am looking for:

- a way to achieve two svg maps next to eachother in qlik sense. Is there maybe a way to duplicate the extension and instead of using two objects of the same extension using 1 object of svgmapextension1 and 1 object of svgmapextenion2? I tried copying the extension and changing the name of the folder and the .qext file, but it didn't work and still only showed one extension.
- **or** a way to modify the javascript so this overlapping doesn't happen? I know that this is a bit much to ask, so even a push in the right direction is fine by me. I tried looking into the svgReader.js and I think the problem is around line 520, because I think this is the place they define the place the object should render? Problem is, I don't know for sure since I am just learning to program (and even that is in python).

Comment: Its probably better to ask the developer by opening issue in GitHub

Comment: The developer deserted the project as far as I can see.